# Determine if a window is topmost or not

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am able to set a windows position as topmost and also setting it no topmost with [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx). But i can't figure out how to check if a window is topmost or not. Is there any Method to check if a window is topmost or not with pinvoke?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [**`GetWindowLong()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx) function to check the [**Extended Window Styles**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx).

Untested, but I believe it should work:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
const int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x0008;

public static bool IsWindowTopMost(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    int exStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    return (exStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST) == WS_EX_TOPMOST;
}
```

Comment: i only think you need to change the type of exStyle to int and the same with ES_EX_TOPMOST

Comment: @Backs : Why? It's a DWORD in C++, which translates to UInt32. So this is the correct. **EDIT:** Oh wait, the `GetWindowLong()` declaration. Okay I'm not sure which to use anymore.

Comment: with WS_EX_TOPMOST you are correct but if i use uint it returns the error that i am missing a cast from int to uint

Comment: @Backs : Fixed. The function declaration should be `int`, but in C++ the flags are of type `DWORD` (`uint`). I changed everything to `int` now, like you said. Microsoft is confusing us. ;)

Comment: ah now it's clear. thank you for the fast fixes and awnsers.

Comment: @Backs : No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: You don't need to do useless check `(exStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST) == WS_EX_TOPMOST` its enough to do `return exStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST`. Its just single bit check, after all. Also, I would better used `DWORD exStyle  = (DWORD)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);`. Using signed integers for boolean operation makes no sense.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer In this case you actually need to check `(exStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST) == WS_EX_TOPMOST` as doing so makes the return value a `bool`, otherwise the compiler will complain that it `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'`.

Comment: As for using signed integers, it doesn't really matter in C# as they are treated more or less the same in cases like this (although unsigned integers aren't CLS-compliant, so if this is a requirement then you must use a signed int). Additionally, `GetWindowLong` returns a `LONG`, which is a 32-bit signed integer, so it would seem Microsoft had no issue with using signed ints for flags. Thus, if we're being really technical about it, it's more correct to have the P/Invoke declaration return an `int`, which is the technical equivalent to `LONG`.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the UI technology you*re using, you can choose of the following two:

- Windows Forms: [`Form.TopMost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx)
- WPF: [`Window.TopMost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can you those properties to check if a certain window is topmost and you can also use these to *set* a window topmost. I'd prefer these in favor of any win32 methods.

Comment: This only works for any window _in his own application_. I bet he's using the WinAPI functions to modify windows of external applications, or else it'd be unnecessary work to use them. :)